# How to merge lines with pattern including "[,],{,}" chars with sed/awk

Tags: bash, sed

I have a text file following a certain formatting which has lines like :

```
{
    "297723": [
        [
          1,
          2
        ],
        [
          5,
          10
        ],
        [
          1,
          157
        ]
      ],
    "369258": [
        [
          3,
          4
        ],
        [
          6,
          11
        ],
        [
          30,
          200
        ]
      ]
}
```

How can I make it look like this ?

```
{"297723": [[1, 2], [5, 10], [1,157]],
{"369258": [[3, 4], [6, 11], [30,200]]}
```

Of course, there are several blocks, I just append the first (which starts with "{" and the last which closes with "}" - in all the rest, there is a number (like "2927723" in my example) which notifies the new block.

Comment: is the input json? why is there extra `{` in expected output... add the code you tried to solve this

Comment: Are you **sure** you want output that has 2 open `{`s but only 1 closing `}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is a valid JSON, so you may apply ***jq*** tool for this case:

```
jq -c '.' yourfile | sed 's/,"/,\n"/'
```

The output:

```
{"297723":[[1,2],[5,10],[1,157]],
"369258":[[3,4],[6,11],[30,200]]}
```

---

- `-c` - print the input in *compact-output* form

Comment: @EdMorton, check my update. As for *missing `{` at start of 2nd line* - that's  doubtful

Comment: agreed. idk JSON well enough to know what she really wants but youd THINK matching braces...